# How to prevent the `| clip` command from appending a newline character?

Tags: windows, command-line, clipboard, git-bash

In Git Bash, when I run the below command:

`echo "foo" | clip`

and paste the output into a text editor, I see a new line character has been appended to the output string:

```
foo
<newline>
```

How can I prevent it from adding the trailing newline character or trim the same after getting appended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from `echo(1)` man page:

```
     -n     do not output the trailing newline
```

so just add the `-n` option to the command: `echo -n "foo" | clip`.